# uploading files to s3 becomes 69 bytes

Tags: go

The following is to use the go-sdk of aws s3 to upload files, but the file size after uploading is inconsistent with the actual file size. Here is the code I wrote:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

// aws s3 putObject example: aws s3api put-object --bucket db-backup-huawen --key truco/rpmlist.txt(上传到bucket的位置) --body ./rpmlist.txt(本地文件)
func main() {

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        MaxRetries:  aws.Int(3),
        Credentials: credentials.NewSharedCredentials("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/aws.ini", "aws-huawen-root"),
        Region:      aws.String("sa-east-1"),
    })

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    s3api := s3.New(sess)

    input := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Body:   aws.ReadSeekCloser(strings.NewReader("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/baxi_MGCenter_FULL_20230211_000001.bak")),
        Bucket: aws.String("db-backup-huawen"),
        Key:    aws.String("truco/baxi_MGCenter_FULL_20230211_000001.bak"),
    }

    res, err := s3api.PutObject(input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(res)

}
```

I have called the api strictly according to the document. no error prompt was found during the execution of the program, I don't understand what is wrong,
the following is the output of the execution program:

[image]

The above is the file I uploaded to s3, but the file size is inconsistent with the actual size:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem:

```
of, err := os.Open(src)
if err != nil {
    return
}

defer of.Close()
```

Comment: To help future visitors, could you describe what the problem was?